# Calculate total price for dynamically generated row in form using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Actually i want to calculate total price for each row which genered daynamically using jquery.The row generated usnig dynamicForm("#plus", "#minus", {limit:20});. Please help me to calculate total price.

```
                    <form action="previewStock.jsp" method="post" onsubmit="return validateAddStock()">
                        <table align="center" style="width: 900px;">
                         <tr>
                             <td colspan="10" align="center">
                                Supplier Name : <select class="hoverr" name="supplierName">
                                    <option value="unknown">Unknown</option>


                                </select>

                                <!--<td>

                                Supplier Mob.</td><td><select class="hoverr" name="supplierMob">
                                        <option>Unknown</option>
                                    </select></td>-->
                                    <input type="text" name="invoiceId" placeholder="Enter Invioce Id" >
                                     <a href="addSupplier.jsp?menuId=3"><input type="button" name="addSupplier" id="addSupplier" value="Add New Supplier"></a>
                             </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="10" align="center"><hr></td></tr>
                        <tr style="background: brown; color:  #ffffff;">
                                <td>Item Name</td>
                                <td>Quantity</td>
                                <td>Unit</td>
                                <td>Price/Unit</td>
                                <td>Total Price</td>
                                <td>Purchase Date</td>
                                <td>Expiry Date</td>
                                <td>MRP</td>
                                <td>Category</td>
                                <td>Description</td></tr>
                            <input type="hidden" name="menuId" value="1"/>
                        <tr id="duplicate">
                        <td><input type="text" name="itemName" id="itemName" value=""  required="true" placeholder="Item Name" class="hoverr"/></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="quantity"id="quantity"  value="" required="true" pattern="[0-9]" size="5" placeholder="Qty." class="hoverr"/></td>
                                             <td>
                                                 <select id="unit" name="unit" required="true" class="hoverr">
                                                          <option value="0">Select</option>
                                                          <option value="Kg">Kg</option>
                                                          <option value="Packet">Packet</option>
                                                          <option value="Litre">Litre</option>
                                                          <option value="Meter">Meter</option>
                                                  </select></td>
                                                        <td><input type="textr" name="pricePerUnit" id="pricePerUnit" size="7" value="" required="true"  placeholder="Price P/U."  class="hoverr"/></td>
                                             <td><input type="text" name="totalPrice" id="totalPrice" size="7" value="" placeholder="Tot. Price" class="hoverr"/></td>
                                             <td><input type="date" name="purchgeDate" id="purchageDate" size="12" value="" placeholder="Pur. Date" onfocus="showCalendar('',this,this,'','holder1',0,30,1)"></td>
                                             <td><input type="date" name="expiryDate" id="expiryDate"  size="12" value="" placeholder="Exp. Date" onfocus="showCalendar('',this,this,'','holder1',0,30,1)"></td>
                                             <td><input type="number" name="MRP" id="MRP" size="14" value="" placeholder="MRP" /></td>
                                             <td><select name="category" class="hoverr" id="category"><option value="0">Select</option></select></td>
                                             <td><textarea name="description" id="description" class="textareaItem" placeholder="Description Here" cols="15" rows="1" class="hoverr"/></textarea></td>
                                             <td><a href="#" id="minus" style="color: black;" ><img src="images/delete.png" width="20" style="float: left;" title="Delete Row"></a></td><td><a href="#" id="plus"><img src="images/addItem.png" width="17" style=" float: right;" title="Add Row"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr><td><div style="display: none; margin-left: 680px;" id="total">Grand Total:<lable for="grandTotal" id="grandTotal"><img src="images/rupee.png" height="14"> <input type="text" name="grandTotal"></lable></div></td></tr><br><br>
                        <tr><td colspan="10" align="center"><hr></td></tr>
                        <tr><td colspan="10" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"></td></tr>
                        </table>
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle for it...

Comment: This is not a great thing to be doing on the browser. Thieves can change the prices and give themselves discounts.  It is OK if you check it on the server as well, but that means writing more code.